# get the DNS name associated with each IP number and then double check that DNS name against the DNS blacklist available

Tags: unix, dns

we have a log file and a dns blacklist

we want to check that if the dns for each ip addresses exist in the dns blacklist or not...if yes we have to write blacklisted in front of the ip addresses 
can anyone help me?

Comment: You can write a simple script to achieve this in any language of your choice just look through the log file and keep checking. If you are facing any issues while doing so than please update your question.

Comment: can you show it in code using unix?